# How to switch-handle-close particular popup window, When multiple popups are opened?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium2, browser-automation

I know how to switch to single popup window, but I do not know how to switch particular popup window when you have more popup windows.

> **Scenario is:** Go to the each and every popup

1. Get the title
2. Perform any action (Click on link) on popup
3. Close the particular popup.

**Test URL:** http://site2.way2sms.com/content/prehome.jsp

> **Below is the sample code:**

```
  import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.junit.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class PopupRnD {
        @Test
      public void test5() throws Exception {
          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          driver.get("http://site2.way2sms.com/content/prehome.jsp");

            String mainwindow=driver.getWindowHandle();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Contact us")).click();

            for(String winHandle :driver.getWindowHandles()){
                driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
                if(driver.getTitle().equals("Real Estate | Property in India | Buy/Sale/Rent Properties | MagicBricks")){
System.out.println("You are in required window");
                    break;
                    } else{
            System.out.println("Title of the page after - switchingTo: " + driver.getTitle());
                }
            }
            driver.switchTo().window(mainwindow);
            driver.quit();
    }
      }
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? By the looks of it, this piece of code would work fine. It will do exactly what you wanted to get done.

Comment: @Yash: I want to switch to a particular popup window (When you have more than 1 popup windows) and perform some actions or close it.

Comment: @QA4it- You have answered the question in the question itself. The sample code above is the perfect example. The 'for' loop enables you to iterate over every window. Combined with the 'if' condition you can pick a window that suits you and take action over it. If you need another example then i can post one where I use a Java Set or List to do the same thing.

Comment: @Yash: Please post your code. Thanks Yash :)..

Comment: @Yash, how are you initializing variable s in your example. I am unable to get the popup window handle.

Answer (score 1):

So here's my code. Not much different from your sample code. I have used a Java Set to store the window handles of pop ups(since `driver.getWindowHandles()` returns a set)

Test url: http://www.popuptest.com/

```
@Test
public void PopupUsingSet() throws InterruptedException{
driver.get("http://www.popuptest.com/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='popuptest12.html']")).click();
String CWH=driver.getWindowHandle();
System.out.println("Current Window Handle: "+driver.getWindowHandle());

    //Adding the windowhandles to a set
s.addAll(driver.getWindowHandles());

    //removing CWH from the set as we want to take actions only on the poopups
    s.remove(CWH);

    //iterating over the popups. Going to each popup, getting the title and the src 
   //of the image displayed and closing them        
    Iterator ii= s.iterator();
while(ii.hasNext()){
    //elements inside the set are of the type object, so we convert them to string 
        driver.switchTo().window(ii.next().toString());
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img")).getAttribute("src"));
    driver.close();
             }
    //bringing the control back to the main window
    driver.switchTo().window(CWH);
```

Hope this helps. I have not used the Java List because it requires unnecessary effort in splitting the list element into usable window handles.

Looking at your example code and the one i wrote it's clear that using an advanced for loop is the more efficient method.

Comment: I forgot to mention one thing. Elements inside the Java Set are automatically sorted according to their values so iterating over them would result in the control being shifted to random pop-ups. It wont follow the sequence in which the pop-ups opened.

Comment: Why using an advanced "for" loop is more efficient? Why usage of iterators is considered advanced method?

Comment: According to JavaDoc, `getWindowHandles()` returns `Set<String>`, so there is no reason to call `toString()` method. Instead, it would be enouth to declare your `s` variable as `Set<String>` and iterator as `Iterator<String>`, as well.

Comment: @Yash - http://www.popuptest.com/ was very much useful