# How to switch pop-up handler using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am working on a application that opens a form to fill up when i click on a button.
I need to switch to that window , fill up the form and come out
I tried this code

Set beforePopup = driver.getWindowHandles();

//code to click on add button to open the pop-up

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body[@id='ext-gen1018']/div[@id='contentPanel-1461']/div[@id='contentPanel-1461-body']/div[@id='campaigns-1464']/div[@id='campaigns-1464-body']/span[@id='campaigns-1464-outerCt']/div[@id='campaigns-1464-innerCt']/div[@id='campaignscoveragegrid-1494']/div[@id='toolbar-1507']/div[@id='toolbar-1507-innerCt']/div[@id='toolbar-1507-targetEl']/a[@id='button-1508']/span[@id='button-1508-btnWrap']/span[@id='button-1508-btnEl']/span[@id='button-1508-btnIconEl']")).click();

```
    Set <String> wndHandler = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator <String> it = wndHandler.iterator();
    String Parent = it.next();
    String Child = it.next();
    driver.switchTo().window(Child);
```

I am getting no such element exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use following code to switch between windows based on the window title. or please go through this link [Link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8416/how-to-switch-handle-particular-popup-window-when-multiple-popup-are-opened-an)

```
 private void handleMultipleWindows(String windowTitle) {
            Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();

            for (String window : windows) {
                driver.switchTo().window(window);
                if (driver.getTitle().contains(windowTitle)) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```